# How to store in TIME data type in MYSQL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js, momentjs

I am using SailsJS and MYSQL database.
I already read the documentation about the data type `TIME` so basically said that you can add as a literal value with the format `HH:MM:SS` as far as I can see in the sample you insert the a new data with:

```
INSERT INTO tests(name,start_at,end_at)
VALUES('Test 2','083000','101500');
```

I also tried use momentjs parsing my string like `moment(00:00:00, 'HH:mm:ss')` according to the documentation you are able to have a value, but after reviewing in the console I noticed this:

```
moment("2020-03-02T00:00:00.000")
```

So automatically create a date for the time that put on.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After research a bit more. I realized that the way you pass in mysql the time is just a string. So I change in my model from this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string', required: true },
    start_at: { type: 'time'},
    end_at: { type: 'time'}
  },
};
```

to this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string', required: true },
    start_at: { type: 'string'},
    end_at: { type: 'string'}
  },
};
```

And then you can store it successfully.